# Wp_logout_url() Security

Tags: wordpress, logout

I changed my code from calling on this function: `wp_logout_url()` when the logout button is clicked, to just calling `www.mysite.com/access?action=logout`.

Users could log out and they get a prompt before they do but is there any vulnerabilities letting users log out of the website this way? Rather than using wp_logout_url()?

Comment: Doesn't `wp_logout_url()` just generate a link to that URL anyway?

Comment: Im not fully sure all what it does iv read the codex but when i hover over the logout button in my theme i see that it has something nounce=*random digits* at the end of the www.mysite.com/access?action=logout, so I'm not sure if that's security, that's why i asked if it's safe to have people log out the way i stated in the original post but when i use just the www.mysite.com/access?action=logout it doesn't show the nounce stuff at the end

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in function?

Comment: Because of the comment i made here regarding the 404 page to the guy who tried to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401345/hide-wp-admin-and-wp-login-php-from-htaccess so i went ahead and tried entering the actual logout link.

Comment: If something as fundamental as the logout function is breaking, god knows what else is.  I would try to sort out that problem first.

Comment: Please take a look at the link i referenced...if you have an input on how to fix my problem regarding the help i asked for then post it over there, for now i just need to know if its safe to hardcode the logout url like that in this question. Two different topics let's not mix them before lurking admins wrongfully close my question.